# fetch two distinct rows with discontinued dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fetch two rows with discontinued dates from a data sample ex: end date of 1st row should be equal to start date of next row and I want to print whole two rows

tried lead but it did not work

```sql
select t1.*
from (select t.*, lead(cast(startdate as date)) over (order by currenykey,cast(enddate as date)) as next_start_date
      from table t 
     ) t1
where enddate <> next_start_date
```

```
    start date          end date    
1   11/6/17 0:00.00     11/13/17 0:00.00    
2   11/13/17 0:00.00    12/26/17 0:00.00    
3   12/26/17 0:00.00    1/8/18 0:00.00    
4   10/22/18 0:11.13    2/25/19 0:16.35    
5   2/25/19 0:16.35     3/4/19 0:09.57    
6   3/4/19 0:09.57      3/11/19 0:12.30    
7   3/11/19 0:12.30     3/18/19 0:10.21    
8   3/18/19 0:10.21     3/25/19 0:09.20    
9   3/25/19 0:09.20     4/1/19 0:10.19
```

I want o print entire rows 3 and 4

Comment: "Didn't work" how?  What RDBMS is this on?  (given that `endDate` still has a time component, that suggests Oracle...)

Comment: ['working' version of query, with proper datatypes](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d870dc/2/0).  If your RDBMs is Oracle, casting to `DATE` will remove the time portion, and will produce strange results.  So what's not working?

Comment: this is on SQL server

Comment: I tried with and without the cast and did not get desired results.

Comment: is there any way this can be done using CTE ?

Comment: I have an answer here that you can use. Let me try to find it. Part of my query does exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on SQL Server 2012 or later you could use the LAG and LEAD functions:

- [LAG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [LEAD (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

For example...

```sql
declare @StackOverflow table (
  [ID] int not null,
  [StartDate] datetime not null,
  [EndDate] datetime not null
);

insert @StackOverflow values
  (1, '11/6/17 0:00.00', '11/13/17 0:00.00'),
  (2, '11/13/17 0:00.00', '12/26/17 0:00.00'),
  (3, '12/26/17 0:00.00', '1/8/18 0:00.00'),
  (4, '10/22/18 0:11.13', '2/25/19 0:16.35'),
  (5, '2/25/19 0:16.35', '3/4/19 0:09.57'),
  (6, '3/4/19 0:09.57', '3/11/19 0:12.30'),
  (7, '3/11/19 0:12.30', '3/18/19 0:10.21'),
  (8, '3/18/19 0:10.21', '3/25/19 0:09.20'),
  (9, '3/25/19 0:09.20', '4/1/19 0:10.19');

select [ID], [StartDate], [EndDate]
from (
  select [ID],
    [StartDate],
    [EndDate],
    [Previous] = cast(lag([EndDate]) over (order by [ID]) as date),
    [Next] = cast(lead([StartDate]) over (order by [ID]) as date)
  from @StackOverflow SO
) SO
where Previous != cast([StartDate] as date)
or Next != cast([EndDate] as date);
```

Which yields:

```
ID  StartDate           EndDate
3   26/12/2017 00:00:00 08/01/2018 00:00:00
4   22/10/2018 00:11:00 25/02/2019 00:16:00
```

Comment: The previous and next variables are not storing the timestamp in the query. Is there any way we can store the timestamp in these variables.

Comment: In SQL Server `timestamp` is a data type and has a specific meaning. Are you wanting to also show the time components of `Previous` and `Next` values? If so, don't `cast(... as date)` them in the nested query, do it in the `where` clause instead.

Comment: yes i want to show  the time components of Previous and Next values. But how can the cast be applied in where clause while we are fetching the values of previous and cast in the nested query

Comment: Looks like if i just remove the cast everywhere including the nested query and the where clause, the timestamps are being stored.

select [ID], [StartDate], [EndDate], [Previous],[Next] 
from (
  select [ID],
    [StartDate],
    [EndDate],
    [Previous] = lag([EndDate]) over (order by [ID]),
    [Next] = lead([StartDate]) over (order by [ID])
  from @StackOverflow SO
) SO
where Previous != [StartDate] 
or Next != [EndDate];

Comment: You should be more precise with your usage of the terms `date`, `datetime` and `timestamp`. They are different data types and have specific meanings to most database administrators and programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is on the right path, with two caveats:

1. You want to convert to dates *for the comparison*.
2. You need to compare both `lead()` and `lag()`.

So:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(startdate) over (order by startdate) as next_startdate,
             lag(enddate) over (order by startdate) as prev_enddate
      from t 
     ) t
where convert(date, enddate) <> convert(date, next_startdate) or
      convert(date, startdate) <> convert(date, prev_enddate) ;
```

That said, I think you are safer with `not exists` subqueries:

```
select *
from t
where (not exists (select 1
                   from t t2
                   where convert(date, t.startdate) = convert(date, t2.enddate)
                  ) or
       not exists (select 1
                   from t t2
                   where convert(date, t.enddate) = convert(date, t2.startdate)
                  )
      ) and
      t.startdate <> (select min(t2.startdate) from t t2) and
      t.startdate <> (select max(t2.startdate) from t t2) ;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5cb0c3b7668d9edd728156012bcae993) is a db<>fiddle.

To understand why, consider what happens if the start date of line 3 changes.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=19eeeb9d2a633b857189601bcaa54ac5) is an example where the two do not produce the same results.